# Calling Reset Zoom manually

Tags: highcharts, zooming

I have a chart where i allowed zooming in/out. 
Each time user zoom in/out "Reset Zoom" appears.

Now I have added a new customize button where i need to show X most updated column data.
I have changed categories and data, but need also to reset the zoom.

Can this be done ? I still want to keep the "Reset Zoom" when user tries to zoom in/out.
PS: I tried doing this.zoomOut() but then the "Reset Zoom" appeared :(

Regards
Chanan

Comment: Could you create jsFiddle? To reset zoom you can also use `chart.x/yAxis[0].setExtremes(null,null)`

Comment: due to company policy am unable to show using jsFiddle.
But the main idea: I have master/detailed charts, where when
selecting the master it will update the detailed  chart.
I also enabled the zoom on the detailed chart.

Now I want to add a custom button on the detailed chart the will remove the plotBand from the master chart, reset the categories in the detailed chart and reset the zoom - currently I have problem removing the "Reset Zoom" button and resetting the zoom

Comment: ps: chart.x/yAxis[0].setExtremes(null,null) didn't work

Comment: Use some fake data in example. I'm not sure how could I help you, when I can't see what have you done. I think this should be possible to achieve.

Answer (score 12):

Pawel's suggestion of calling

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null,null);
```

does work, btw, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/tvHg6/

However, although the chart zooms out, the resetZoom button is still hanging around, not sure how to hide it.  Calling chart.resetZoomButton.hide() hides it, but it does so permanently.

Comment: You can do like "chart.zoomOut()". it will hide Reset Zoom button as well. see here http://jsfiddle.net/tvHg6/18/

Comment: It works like a charm. those who are looking to zoom out a chart programmatically. This is the one for you

Comment: Works with React Highcharts as well (onClick). Thanks @mpeac.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29026981/1280252)

```
chart.zoom()
```

But keep in mind that calling `chart.zoom()` does not trigger `chart.events.selection` event. Which is triggered if you click on "Reset button" manually or programmatically `$('.highcharts-button').click();`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reset the zoom on an external button click then do it as follows:

```
$("#YourOwnZoomBtnID").click(function(){ 

    $('.highcharts-button').click();
});
```

If you want to hide the Inbuilt Reset Button of highcharts then you can do it as follows:

```
xAxis: { categories: xAxisCategories
                ,events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function() {
        $('.highcharts-button').hide();
      }
    }}
```

jsfiddle example is here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3572/)

Thanks
Kalyan

Comment: Your example is not working. Reset button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just called the button's click event and it worked fine.

given: v_chart is variable for Highcharts chart;

```
if (typeof v_chart.resetZoomButton !== 'undefined') {
    v_chart.resetZoomButton.element.onclick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. hide the original reset button

> ```
>  chart: {
>             resetZoomButton: {
>                     theme: {
>                         display: 'none'
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

2. take care of the event

> ```
>  buttons: {
>                     resetButton: {
>                         symbol: 'url(redo_icon.svg)',
>                         _titleKey: "resetZoom",
>                         y: 20,
>                         x: -20,
>                         onclick: function () {
>                             this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null,null);
>                             this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(null,null)
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation - user zooms, we add a 'save this zoom stage' button, user clicks the button, we save the new min/max time, but now we have to make the reset zoom button disappear.

This code did it and the button returns if the user zooms even further afterwards:

```
chart.resetZoomButton.hide();
chart.resetZoomButton = chart.resetZoomButton.destroy();
```