# Datetime Highchart with selection event, set wrongly the extremes

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to do the same as regular zooming, but I use:

```
events : { selection : function(event) {
```

instead of the regular zooming (it is part of something --> [Launch Highcharts zooming programmatically (after a selection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028504/launch-highcharts-zooming-programmatically-after-a-selection))

The problem. When I select (via selection, like zooming) an interval (for example something between 00:00 and 01:00) the zoom shows another area. How can I solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/FSfR2/4/

Comment: Your setExtrmes is not correct, I adviceto familair with: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've overcomplicated your problem, just pass the min and max you get in the event to the setExtremes function

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(event.xAxis[0].min,  event.xAxis[0].max);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/wmyM4/